# Evaluation of XPath in Conditional Goto in SOAP UI

Tags: xpath, soapui

I am trying to implement a simple loop in SOAP UI 4.6.1. According to the documentation the 'Conditional Goto' step should allow me to evaluate a XPath expression against the previous response.

For given response:

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
   <soap:Body>
      <ns2:GetVeryImportantDetailsResponse xmlns:ns2="http://www.bigcompany.com/XYZ/VeryImportantService/V1">
         <Status Reason="You did everything wrong again" Code="nok"/>
      </ns2:GetVeryImportantDetailsResponse>
   </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

I want to jump to another step if Code equals 'nok'. Unfortunately I cannot achieve this in any way. Some examples:

```
exists("//Status/Code[text() = 'nok']") -> true
exists("//Status/Code[text() = 'ok']") -> true

exists(//Status/Code[text() = "nok"]) -> false
exists(//Status/Code[text() = "ok"]) -> false

starts-with("//Status/Code", 'nok') -> false
starts-with("//Status/Code", 'ok') -> false

starts-with(//Status/Code, 'nok') -> false
starts-with(//Status/Code, 'ok') -> false
```

Is this a bug in SOAP UI or am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're doing it wrong - your XPath syntax is wrong.

Try: `exists(//Status[@Code = 'nok'])`.

Comment: Thanks. I did not know why forgot that attributes are accessed with @. The following expressions also works: //Status/@Code = 'nok' and
starts-with(//Status/@Code, 'nok')